# Magento 2: best practice cache management

Tags: magento2, cache

I just installed Magento 2 and noticed that the caches are all disabled by default. Should I enabled them or leave them disabled? Does it make any different?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to develop some theme or modules, then better to leave it disabled otherwise you will need to refresh it every time. If you need magento be as fast as it can - enable. It has a difference - this impact on loading page speed

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Understood.I am not developing themes or modules, so I will enable them when the website is ready to go live.